# Simplest way to implement time-out in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

How can I set timer for each iteration in a loop?

```
for i in range(0,n):
    subprocess.call()
```

If the call takes longer than a specified time, it should be cancelled and loop should move on to next iteration. Thus, it will prevent loop getting stuck in a function/subprocess call.

Comment: 'If something takes longer than a specified time, loop should move on to next iteration.' Can you explain? What is 'something'? What is meant by 'move on'?

Comment: In my opinion, the question is quite clear in the sense of expressing the idea. Let there are several tasks executed one by one. If the task takes longer, let the task is canceled and possibly another task is started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let your Python code continue while the subprocess executes by using `Popen` instead of `call`. You can set timers using [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html). Put those together and you have something like:

```
def handler(signum, frame):
    raise MyError

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)

for i in range(0,n):
    p = subprocess.Popen(...)
    try:
        signal.alarm(1) # 1 second timer
        p.wait()
        signal.alarm(0) # clear the timer
    except MyError:
        p.kill()
```